# $H = [1,\infty)$ with $d(x,y) = |\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{y}|$ is not Compact by covers

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

Let (M,d) be a metric space where M = (0, $\infty$) and $d(x,y) = |\frac{1}{x} -  \frac{1}{y}|$

Prove that $H = [1,\infty)$ is not compact by covers.

H is clearly bounded and closed, so I am unsure as to how the proof would work. I would start by establishing {${G_\alpha}$}$_{\alpha\in\mathbb I}$ a cover of H. But I do not know how to proceed.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. I was thinking in $H$ with the usual metric. It is.

Comment: @Bumblebee It is clearly not defined as 0 doesn't belong in M

Comment: I figured it later. Note that $x\mapsto \dfrac1{x}$ is an isomerty of $M,$ then the solution is obvious.

Comment: What is $M$? Which metric are you using on $H$? $H$ is not a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual, Euclidean metric. $H$ is a bounded metric space with the metric $d$ but this doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $D(x,y)=|x-y|$ be the usual metric of $\mathbb{R}$. I'll try to make everything as clear as possible:

The Heine-Borel theorem is the following:

> **Theorem**: Let $A$ be a nonempty subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Then $A$ is compact, as a subset of the metric space $(\mathbb{R},D)$, if,  and only if,
>
> 1. There exists $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $A\subseteq[a,b]$; and
> 2. $A$ is a closed subset of $(\mathbb{R},D)$.

Here's the problem

- The metric $d$ is not $D$. The set $H$ is $d$-bounded, but **not** $D$-bounded.
- By the Heine-Borel theorem, $(H,D_{H\times H})$ is **not compact**, because it is an unbounded subset of $(\mathbb{R},D)$.
- The map $(H,d)\to((0,1],D_{(0,1]\times(0,1]})$, $x\mapsto 1/x$, is an isometry. By the Heine-Borel theorem, $((0,1],D_{(0,1]\times(0,1]})$ is not compact, because it is not closed, so $(H,d)$ is also not compact.

Comment: Nothing you've said here is incorrect. That said, it isn't helpful to the OP.

Comment: @CameronBuie A very considerate comment.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $(0, 1]\to H:x\mapsto \frac1x$ is an isometry and therefore a homeomorphism.

Here $(0,1]$ is endowed with the usual metric. You can build a suitable open cover of it and transport it.

Comment: Is there not a direct way of proving it?

Comment: @FSteval You don't *need* to have this point of view. It is just a way of making the solution more natural.

Comment: I have reviewed the answer but I do not see why we can use an open cover in the new metric space (0,1]

Comment: @FSteval The "new" metric space is the **usual** half-open interval. Open sets there are well understood. Use for instance $\{(\frac1 n,1]:n\in\Bbb N\}$.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a direct way:  take the open cover $\{G_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, where $G_n = [1, n+1)$.

Comment: How does that work?

Comment: The sets are open in the relative topology of $[1, \infty)$, and the union of any finite subfamily is a proper subset of $[1, \infty)$.

Comment: user539887 You are under no obligation to continue the discussion with the asker, if it makes you unhappy. But, being confused is not against the rules.